# Server hacked? Binary /usr/lib/os-release!

Tags: hacking

Server: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

I was going to generate an SSL certificate as usual with certbot but suddenly it started to give a weird error:

> An unexpected error occurred:
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 0: invalid start byte
> Please see the logfile '/tmp/tmpmd32ty55/log' for more details.

I debugged the sources of certbot but couldn't find what was going wrong. Clearly there was a file read by certbot that had some garbage in it preventing being parsed.

Then I found the problem was with this file:

> /usr/lib/os-release

I opened it with vi and got a binary file. The output of

```
sourcecode@sourcecode:~$ file /usr/lib/os-release
```

is:

> /usr/lib/os-release: PGP/GPG key public ring (v4) created Mon Jan 19
> 15:40:57 2015 RSA (Encrypt or Sign) 8192 bits
> MPI=0xbfd289769695aada...

I don't know this file but I guess it should be a text file, so I checked another server of mine and its /usr/lib/os-release is a text file as I thought.

**Do you think my server has been hacked?**

Comment: Well, if you had provided information about what distribution and version you are using someone could check if that file is valid or not ...

Comment: added to post, thanks (Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS)

Comment: See if it matches `~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg`  Most likely it was overwritten by some accident or bad script.